# Merging data out multiple workbooks in Excel PowerQuery

Tags: database, excel, powerquery

I want to create a PowerQuery in Excel. I have 10 workbooks with same format to each table in first sheet. I want to merge them all into a one main workbook with the data out of this tables. All workbooks is in the same folder.[It is the format i built on:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b6Qj.png)

Comment: Do you have a question? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Start with a query from file > from folder.  Then use the Combine Binaries, which will prompt you to define which element from each file you want to combine.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-files-in-a-folder-with-Combine-Binaries-Power-Query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4